# Why are the function parameters not being updated inside recursive python function?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

I was trying to find the inorder successor of node in a Binary Search Tree. My code is basically doing an inorder traversal and keeping track of the next node by using a counter variable:

```
class Solution:
    # returns the inorder successor of the Node x in BST (rooted at 'root')
    ans = None 
    def inorderSuccessor(self, root, x):
        counter = 0
        answer = self.findNode(root, x, counter)
        return self.ans
     
    def findNode(self, root, x, counter):
        if root == None:
            return None
        self.findNode(root.left, x, counter)
        if counter == 1:
            counter += 1
            self.ans = root
            return root
        if root.data == x.data:
            ###counter becomes 1 here, when it finds the x node.
            counter += 1
        ###but it is not updated in the params.    
        self.findNode(root.right, x, counter)
```

This does not work because the counter variable is never updated by the recursive call.

But if I make `counter` a global variable, it works:

```
class Solution:
    # returns the inorder successor of the Node x in BST (rooted at 'root')
    ans = None 
    counter = 0
    def inorderSuccessor(self, root, x):
        # Code here
        answer = self.findNode(root, x)
        return self.ans
     
    def findNode(self, root, x):
        if root == None:
            return None
        self.findNode(root.left, x)
        if self.counter == 1:
            self.counter += 1
            self.ans = root
            return root
        if root.data == x.data:
            self.counter += 1
        self.findNode(root.right, x)
```

Can anyone please explain this property of Python? Why doesn't it update the function parameters while making a recursive call?

Comment: Please do tell, if there is any clarification required in the question?

Comment: The way your code is written, if `root.data` and `x.data` are equal, then `counter` will be incremented for future recursive calls. Are you sure that condition is true? Consider debugging your code and seeing if the condition trips

Comment: This happens because arguments to functions are passed by value, not by name. The value that `counter` currently has is copied to a variable that is local to the function. If the function changes the value of that local variable, then that has no bearing on the variable of which the value was passed as argument.

Comment: Yes, this condition is true whenever the root pointer meets the x node, counter is 1 in that case.@SilvioMayolo

Comment: @trincot that's interesting to know, do you know any other way in which we can bypass this, without using a global variable

Comment: @trincot arguments to function **are absolutely not passed by value**. That would imply that the function gets a *copy* of the object, which it does not. It isn't passed by reference either, or by name, python uses "call by object sharing", which is equivalent to assigning to a local variable in the function

Comment: @krtchen you aren't using global variables *anywhere*.  Those are class variables and instance variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, indeed, it is assigning to a local variable in the function. Any change the function makes to that variable has no bearing to the callers variable. `counter = 0; fun(counter)` is no different from `counter = 0; fun(0)`.

Comment: @trincot yes, my point is, it isn't call by value. If it *were* call by value, say `f` mutated it's input, something like `def f(x): x.append(10)`, then `y = []; f(y), print(y)` would print `[]`. values are *never copied* when passed to functions

Comment: Numbers cannot be mutated.

Comment: @trincot it doesn't matter, *it still isn't copied* and python is *never call by value*. Yes, for immutable objects the effect is the same. Although note, you *can* mutate integers, if you are willing to use `ctypes` to dig into the guts of the object, and you will see, the `int` object is indeed not copied

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay, correct- those are class and instance variables. So, a python function can never alter parameters, right? Do you know any languages which do that?

Comment: @krtchen what do you mean by "alter parameters"? You can *mutate* the object if it is mutable, *python never uses call by reference*, so *assignment to the paremter* will *never* affect a **variable** in the caller. Of course, if you mutate the object, those changes will be seen by *any reference to that object*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried def f(x): x.append(10), then y = []; f(y), print(y), it gave [10]

Comment: @krtchen yes, again, *that shows that python is not call by value*

Comment: That depends what you call the value of course.

Comment: @trincot no, not really. This evaluation strategy, the one python uses, is well defined and comes from CLU which is a huge influence in Python. The fact that people often  misuse the term "call by value" to describe the evaluation strategy of, say, Java (where being a non-pure OOP language at least it is understandable). But saying Python is call by value is just mistaking implementation for semantics. Say I create an implementation of Python using Fotran and exclusive use call by reference to implement Python, that doesn't make *Python's* evaluation strategy call by reference

Comment: That's fine. My use of *value* may not be in line with that. I used the term as is compared with `is` -- identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `findNode(root, x, counter)`, then if `findNode` *assigns* a new value to `counter`, this is an assignment to the variable that is local to `findNode` -- the parameter variable. Such assignment is not to this `counter` variable that is named in the function call.

More to the algorithm: it is not necessary to have such a `counter` variable. You can instead use the following algorithm:

Walk down the tree according to the BST logic. When the `x.data` is less than the current node's data, then go left, else go right. Every time you go left, keep track of where you came from, as it might turn out to be the successor we are looking for.

Once you reach the end of this downward path in the tree, recall which node was the last node where the decision was to go left. That is the successor.

Code:

```
    def inorderSuccessor(self, root, x):
        candidate = None
        while root:
            if x.data < root.data:
                candidate = root
                root = root.left
            else:
                root = root.right
        return candidate
```